# How can I replace x-axis labels with pre-determined symbols?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to take a simple plot and change the x-axis so it appears to be measured in terms of certain symbols that are used in the physics literature. See the image below for an example.

[image: Example band structure which illustrates the axis convention.]

I will rephrase this as follows: I have some set of numerical coordinates which trace out the curves in my plot. For equal spacings on the x-axis (say once every 100 points), I want to label the line $x=100\,n$ with a symbol.

I don't know how to do this. The documentation provided by Mathematica didn't help me. This doesn't seem like something done by just changing the ticks settings.

Comment: Provide sample data to work with

Comment: The curves can be anything. You can just plot a simple function if you like. This is just an illustration of how I want to format the axis, not real data.

Comment: [`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done using either `Ticks` if you're using axes or `FrameTicks` if you're using a frame on your plot. I made up a plot since I'm not sure the exact data matters.

Most of the code below is flair to make the graph look a bit nicer. The important bit is `FrameTicks`. I've told MMA to use its best judgement for 3 of the 4 sides of the graph. For plots, the order is usually `{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`, though for certain things you can get away with only 2 arguments `{x-argument, y-argument}`.

For each side of the frame, `FrameTicks` is expecting a list of ticks and the label to put on those ticks, so in place of `bottom` from the above list, I would put something like `{{x-value1, "x-label1"}, {x-value2, "x-label2"}, ...}`. It is also possible to specify the lengths of the ticks in this way: `{{x-value1, "x-label1", {insidelength1, outsidelength1}}, {x-value2, "x-label2", {insidelength2, outsidelength2}}, ...}`.

```
Plot[
 Piecewise[
  {{-(x - 5)^2 + 50, 0 <= x <= 10},
   {-(x - 10)^2 + 25, 10 < x < 15}}],
 {x, 0, 15},
 Axes -> False,
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {{"E (eV)", None}, {"k-space", None}},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[16, Black],
 FrameTicks -> 
   {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{{0, "K"}, {5, "Γ"}, {10, "M"}, {15, "K"}}, Automatic}},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Epilog -> {
   Dashing[{0.001, 0.01}],
   Line[{{0, -1}, {0, 25}}],
   Line[{{5, -1}, {5, 50}}],
   Line[{{10, -1}, {10, 25}}],
   Line[{{15, -1}, {15, 0}}]
   }
 ]
```

[image: Kspace plot of random function.]

Comment: Beautiful, thanks a lot! Much easier to understand in the context of using a frame.